# send data to modal with laravel and vueJS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I´m traying to send data of my array data to one modal, but always in web console i can see this message:

```
 [Vue warn]: Property or method "nombreUsuario" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property
```

in my component i´m creating a modal and i thinked that i could pass this data to my modal, but i can´t.
i´m traying declare one variable in export deafult of my component, but always returned me a error.

i´m showing in internet very much examples that how to do this, but i can´t.

I appreciate all help

My actual code is:

**componentVUE**

```
  <template>
    <div class="tabla-usuarios">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Dirección</th>
                <th>Editar</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ datosUsuario.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ datosUsuario.nombre }}</td>
                    <td>{{ datosUsuario.email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ datosUsuario.direccion }}</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create">Editar</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


        <div class="modal fade" id="create">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                <span>×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" :nombreUsuario="nombreUsuario">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="direccion">Direccion:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        
</template>



<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                datosUsuario: [],
                isOpen: false,
            };

        },
        created: function () {
            this.cargar();
        },
        methods: {
            cargar: function () {
                let url = "/getDatosPersonales";
                axios
                    .get(url)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.datosUsuario = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You don't have `nombreUsuario` defined in your properties anywhere in your Vue code. Vue is very picky when it comes to undefined properties.

Comment: thanks you for your response. but where have to define my property¿?? because y have one return and always returned this message. i trayed out, but always this meesage

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if it's complaining about `:nombreUsuario` or `"nombreUsuario"`. What are you trying to do there? You may want `v-model` instead of `:numbreUsuario`

Comment: i want send to my modal nombreUsuario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to pass information to a modal is to pass it through a function and store it in a Vue property. First, in your loop, change your button to this:

```
<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create" @click="setSelectedItem(datosUsuario)">Editar</a></td>
```

Then you want to add both the property and the method:

```
<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                datosUsuario: [],
                isOpen: false,
                selectedItem: {}
            };

        },
        created: function () {
            this.cargar();
        },
        methods: {
            cargar: function () {
                let url = "/getDatosPersonales";
                axios
                    .get(url)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.datosUsuario = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
            },
            setSelectedItem(item) {
                this.selectedItem = item;
            }
        },
    };
</script>
```

Then it's real easy to get that data back into your modal:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" v-model="selectedItem.nombre">
</div>
```

You can also use the selectedItem in other functions, such as when submitting it back to the server.